# Particle Modifier - Repeat for Infinity

Tags: animation, mesh, particles

I'm wanting to create a wave-like effect where particles are emitted from a mesh every X number of frames.

Particle modifiers have a Start and End frame setting, but what if I just want that particle modifier to repeat itself for infinity?  **I want the particle system to spawn some particles, stop for a set time, then spawn some more particles**, creating waves of particles that will keep coming forever.

I don't know how to do this with blender.  It is a start and end particle system.  That's it.  What can I do?

Comment: can you explain better the concept of "infinity"?  why do you want a blender animation to last forever?

Comment: I'm trying to create an effect that is like waves.  I want waves of particles, so the animation needs to emit particles, stop, and then emit again, and continue doing that for infinity.

Comment: What's your desired output? A video that last 1 hour? A looping video? You want to use blender as demo machine?

Comment: I'm making a video that does not loop.  I just didn't want to have to duplicate that particle system over and over and change the start/end times to make the wave effect.  I think there should be a better to do it.

Comment: Do you know animation nodes add-on?

Comment: @Sanbaldo I'm interested How to ... I would appreciate an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control particles emission with animated Black & White Color influencing an emission Density.

[image]

In this example

- particles are emitted from circle's vertices (but source can be Face or Volume as well)
- by default are particles emitted all the time
- with Texture (Color) you can influence density of emitted particles

Technically you don't let blender to stop / start emitting particles, but texture says how much dense particles should be emited. Black color means emit zero particles, White means full density of emitted particles.

### Animation Sequence

Go to *Particles Properties* editor > *Texture* and ad *New*.
Switch tab to *Texture Properties* and select type *Image*, simply because it is black by default, so you don't have to setup nothing else. Just go to Influence panel and enable *Density*

[image]

Now you have two options

- animate color from black to white or
- I decided to animate *Density* parametr from 0 to 1

... means zero influence of black density - it let particle system emit as normal, one means full influence of black density that is zero particles.
*If it is too overhead you can choose first option and in Texture enable Color Ramp and animate color. Result is the same.*

Set one cycle of keyframes and go to *Graph* editor and change interpolation <kbd>T</kbd> to *Constant* that will works like switch ON/OFF in time.

### Animation Repeat

To let blender repeat this animation open *Graph's* editor properties (side panel) <kbd>N</kbd>, go to *Modifiers* tab and add *Cycles*

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good answer to my problem.  Thanks!  I could use more details, though, if you don't mind :)

Comment: Great!  I'm sure this will work.  Thanks for the tip.  I have one question:  Is there a way to make the particles invisible until "spawned"?

Comment: I m going to check if General time or Size helps, but it's wierd they appear anyway. To work with particles is a pain, mainly due a lack of proper cache update. Many changes in setup is ignored and only change of particles number solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make the last frame the copy of the first one, but mind you: the anim can go forever **only** in the viewport and timeline until you pause/stop it. Once you **rendered** it you need to loop-play it with your external player.