# Patricles birth rate/count

Tags: animation, particles

Particle emission system has control over total amount of particles to create, but is there any way to control amount of particles to spawn at once?

For example having 120 particles over 120 will produce 1 per second. How can I change it to 2 per second?

I guess I can make duplicate of that particle system and change seed so all of the settings will be the same. However that always becomes a problem if I need more than 1 per second since in order to make changes I will have to perform same routine over all systems or to copy them again and again after each tweak I make.

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187074/86978

Comment: @Chris I've followed that solution and particle system looks buggy. That advice in theory should work but in my case particles sometimes spawn at density 1 and then disappear or spawn but without gravity. Example file ends up with particles scattering randomly. Dont know why. Checked in 2.92 and 2.93

Comment: 120 particles over 120 frames produces 1 per frame, not per second. The rate per second depends on how many FPS you have set. To get 2 per frame over 120 frames you have to set it to 240 particles. But you can't actually set a rate and theoretically those particles are generated randomly. So they are 2 per frame on average but not necessarily exactly 2 on each frame.